# Navigation wont hit bottom of screen

Tags: html, css

So this might be relatively simple but I'm obviously missing something here. I've probably been looking at it for far too long. I'm trying to make navigation menu go to the bottom of the screen. As of now it only goes down to the space needed to fit all the nav links in blocks.

I'm trying to get the box itself to reach the bottom of the screen, not the 7th nav link. So, the 7th nav link shouldn't be stretching down to fit (it should keep its padding size)...the box containing it should.

HTML and CSS code:

```css
    *{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }
    
    html,body{
       font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
       background-color: pink;
       color: white;
    }
    
    #wrapper{
       margin: 0 auto;
       min-width: 320px;
       max-width: 1600px;
    }
    
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
       color:#FEBC11;
       text-align: center;
    }
    
    nav{
       width: 100%;
    }
    
    nav a{
       display: block;
       color: white;
       text-decoration: none;
       padding: .5rem; 0rem;
       border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    nav .nav_link{
       text-align: center;
       background-color: blue;
       width: 240px;
    }
    
    nav #nav_logo{
       border-bottom: none; 
       background-color: transparent;
       text-decoration: none;
       color:#FEBC11;
    }
    
    nav .logo h1{
       text-align: left;
       padding-left: .5rem; 
       font-size: 1rem;
       padding-bottom: .5rem;
       padding-top: .5rem;
       background-color: #333;
    }
    
    nav a:hover{
       text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    nav a.current{
       background-color: black;  
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
   <ul>
      <li class="logo"><h1><a id="nav_logo" href="/index.php">Title</a></h1></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">5</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">6</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">7</a></li>                           
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Someone tell me what silly thing I missed please XD

https://jsfiddle.net/yoxgksp3/

EDIT: I probably should have mentioned, I want to keep the title bar at the top of the screen.This picture should help get it across. This has nothing to do with mine, but it helps to show https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZCJX.jpg

Comment: Do you try "position:absolute;bottom:0;"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **move** the title <li> to a <header> outside of <nav>.
2. **update** css replacing `nav #nav-logo` with `header #nav-logo` and other ocurrences of former nav (now header)
3. **add** this css **rule**:

```css
nav ul{
   float: left;
   background: blue;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

4. and **if** you **don't** want **scroll** to appear, add `overflow: hidden` inside the `html, body` css rule.

here's the code:

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

html,body{
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   background-color: pink;
   color: white;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper{
   margin: 0 auto;
   min-width: 320px;
   max-width: 1600px;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
   color:#FEBC11;
   text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
   float: left;
   background: blue;
   height: 100vh;
}

nav a{
   display: block;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none; /* remove underline */
   padding: .5rem; 0rem;
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

nav .nav_link{
   text-align: center; /* center all the links but the KACM */
   background-color: blue;
   width: 240px;
}

header #nav_logo{
   border-bottom: none; /* remove border bottom from KACM */
   background-color: transparent;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#FEBC11;
}

header.logo h1{
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: .5rem; /* moves KACM to the right from the border */
   font-size: 1rem;
   padding-bottom: .5rem;
   padding-top: .5rem;
   background-color: #333;
}

nav a:hover{
   text-decoration: underline;
}

nav a.current{
   background-color: black;  
}
```

```html
<header class="logo"><h1><a id="nav_logo" href="/index.php">Title</a></h1></header>
<nav class="navigation">
   <ul>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">5</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">6</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">7</a></li>                           
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This got it. I guess  jian dan was on the right track after all. Sorry :(. Thank you warkentien2

Comment: there's never a perfect way to position things on the screen. The more you know, more ways you can tackle the same problem. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1600px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #FEBC11;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* remove underline */
  padding: .5rem;
  0rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
nav .nav_link {
  text-align: center;
  /* center all the links but the KACM */
  background-color: blue;
  width: 240px;
}
nav #nav_logo {
  border-bottom: none;
  /* remove border bottom from KACM */
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FEBC11;
}
nav .logo h1 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  /* moves KACM to the right from the border */
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  background-color: #333;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
nav a.current {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1><a id="nav_logo" href="#">Title</a></h1>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can I change the html? for example, move "title" outside the navigation

Comment: I would prefer not as it is a link itself